# Swift Universal Links no longer working app is not showing up

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate, associated-domains

I set up `Universal Links` in my app and when testing it a month ago it was working perfectly fine. I published my app last week in the App-Store and wanted to add `Universal-Links` today but they are no longer working. On my Website you are no longer redirected to the App.

My AASA (my website: https://wishlists-app.de/apple-app-site-association):

```
{
"webcredentials": {
  "apps": [ "SN26HDFT24.com.ckbusiness.Wishlists" ]


},
   
"applinks": {
"apps": [],
"details":
[
    {
    "appID": "SN26HDFT24.com.ckbusiness.Wishlists",
    "paths": ["*"]
    }
]
}
}
```

`Signing & Capabilities`:

[image]

I can't remember changing anything. Does this have something to do with that the App is now live? Or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the `entitlement` file into my build phase! I also put the ASAA into `.well-known` so it is no longer public.